# ¿Como guardar datos de formulario y evitar duplicado?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, formularios

Estoy haciendo una web para gestionar una agenda de atención, se un poco de js pero no lo suficiente... Se que tendré que recurrir a ajax, mysql, php o alguno de estos. 
Mi intención es guardar la fecha con: el mes, día, y horas, en una base de datos *y a la vez enviarlas a mi mail para después vincularlas a google calendar* ¿como puedo almacenar estos datos?El fin de hacerlo es evitar fechas y horas duplicadas...
El formulario es algo simple basado en boostrap, hay algunos rastros de un un js para evitar que la hora de entrada sea después que la de salida.

Surge un problema con las horas pues si elijo por ejemplo  desde las 13:00 a las 17:00 al guardar es importante que las 14 15 y 16 hrs también comprendan esta selección.

Alguna guía a la que pueda acudir? Más que nada necesito el camino que tengo que seguir, busque por separado los temas pero después no se como unirlos.
De antemano gracias!

~

```
<form action="prog.php" method="post" name="formulario" id="formu" onsubmit="return comprobar()">
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-1s">
       <label for="inputState">Mes</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="mes" class="form-control">

        <option>enero</option>
        <option>febrero</option>
        <option>marzo</option>
        <option>abril</option>
        <option>mayo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-1">
      <label for="inputState">Dia</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="dia" value="" class="form-control">

       <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
      </div>    
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputState">Entrada</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="entrada" class="form-control" value="">
        <option>12:00</option>
        <option>13:00</option>
        <option>14:00</option>
        <option>15:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputState"> Salida</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="salida" class="form-control" value=""> 
        <option>13:00</option>
        <option>14:00</option>
        <option>15:00</option>
        <option>16:00</option>
        <option>17:00</option>
      </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

~

Comment: Saludos te sugiero revisar https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Te falta bastante, tu pregunta es muy amplia.  Intenta enfocarte en una cosa a la vez y preguntar algo mas especifico,

Comment: JCLXS me ha guiado y comprendido bastante, mi conflicto ahora esta en como recolectar los distintos campos del formulario para unirlos en una misma columna de mi base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL crea tu tabla, y cuando crees el campo fecha_registro elijes el tipo de dato que recibirá, en este caso es del tipo **"DATETIME"** el cual puede manejar todo lo referente a fecha, hora, minutos y segundos. Después en tu formulario solo debes recoger las parte que compondrán tu fecha, si es que quieres armarla a modo, en otro caso podría ser la fecha del día automática con la función "Date" de PHP... **date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');** puedes meterlo en un input de tu formulario. Después para filtrar puedes hacer una comparación con un rango definido algo como...

```
$myfechaForm = $_POST['fechadelform'];
$fechaINI = "2019-07-25:13:00:00";  <-- Puedes usar la "date de php" para crear la fecha
$fechaFIN = "2019-07-25:17:00:00";

if($myfechaForm >= $fechaINI && $myfechaForm <= $fechaFIN){

AQUÍ EJECUTAS LA SENTENCIA SQL PARA INSERTAR LOS DATOS A TU TABLA CON LA FECHA CORRECTA

} else {

  echo "REGISTRO FUERA DEL HORARIO";
}
```

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias! mas no se como "recoger las partes que comprenden la fecha...", agradecería aun más...

Comment: Simplemente recoge los campos de tu formulario y después en php puedes armar la fecha concatenando fechaForm + horaForm + minutosForm + segundosForm y guardarlo en una sola variable que sera la que vas a comparar con el rango que pongas.

Comment: Comprendo, pero no se como `<?php
include "cn.php"

$fechadelform = CONCAT(mes+dia+entrada+salida)
$fecha = $_POST["fechadelform"];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO reserva(fecha_Registro) VALUES ("$fecha")";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if (!resultado){

 echo "Error al programar fecha"

}   else{
 echo "registrado correctamente"

}
mysqli_close($conexion);`

Comment: de momento solo intento encajar el form en la columna :(

Comment: $fecha = $_POST['mes'].":".$_POST['dia'].":".$_POST['hora'];

Comment: Un genio compañero! Gracias por tu paciencia, eres el mejoor!!